# I get this exception when i use this script on my masterpage

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, telerik

I get this exception when i use this script on my masterpage

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function SetSession() {'<%=Session["ShowHjælpBox"] = "Test" %>' };
</script>
```

I get the exception when i go to one of my pages where i have a telerik component (Autocompletebox) this confuses me alot, please help me -.-

```
Exception:
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Der blev udløst en undtagelse af typen 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException'. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Please, see whether wrapping the code block, generating the exception, within RadCodeBlock resolves the error. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Samlingen Controls kan ikke ændres, for objektet indeholder kodeblokke (dvs. <% ... %>).
   ved System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child)
   ved Telerik.Web.SkinRegistrar.RegisterCssReference(Page page, Type registerType, String url)
   ved Telerik.Web.SkinRegistrar.RegisterCssReference(Page page, Type registerType, String url)
   ved Telerik.Web.SkinRegistrar.RegisterCssReferences(ISkinnableControl control)
   ved Telerik.Web.UI.RadDataBoundControl.RegisterCssReferences()
   ved Telerik.Web.UI.RadDataBoundControl.ControlPreRender()
   ved Telerik.Web.UI.RadAutoCompleteBox.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   ved System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   ved System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   ved System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   ved System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   ved System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   ved System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   ved System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   ved System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   ved System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   ved System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   ved System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   ved System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   ved System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   ved System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   ved System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   ved System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   ved System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   ved ASP.tidsbestilling_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) i c:\Users\cc\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\6184c3c9\f93c9d53\App_Web_ix30hemr.0.cs:linje 0
   ved System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   ved System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

If anyone have another way to add a session by clicking on a button please tell me, ps i dont want a postback on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I can read the exception properly, but did you try wrapping the server code block in a RadCodeBlock control:

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock runat="server" ID="RadCodeBlock1">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function SetSession() {
            '<%=Session["ShowHjælpBox"] = "Test" %>'
        };
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

On a side note - I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but this code will render the following on your page:

```
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function SetSession() {
                'Test'
            };
        </script>
```

which is not really a JS function that will set a SERVER session variable. You simply cannot do this in JS. JS runs in the browser, the Session is on the server. Thus, you need some form of postback that knows about the session in order to set it on a user action. Perhaps this blog post will give you some ideas: http://www.telerik.com/blogs/different-ways-to-make-a-request-to-the-server.

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetSession()
{
    var userName = "Test";
    '<%Session["ShowHjælpBox"] = "' + userName + '"; %>';         
}
</script>
```

Comment: This does not work '<%Session["ShowHjælpBox"] = "' + userName + '"; %>';';'' this does, but courses the page to refresh all the time. And it dosnt solve the problem